# How to Make Suit Of Card (Order) Have an effect on the resultant drawn card

Tags: java, class, constructor

My goal is to modify the program given (The 4 classes) By allowing the suit to take an affect on the result of the program. In general the user is given a card than the user is proceeded to guess whether the next card will have a higher numerical value. However, I'm not so sure on how to modify it to take into account the suit order. PLEASE NOTE THAT I NEEDED TO PUT THIS MUCH CODE, because the resultant input from people helping me would need to be incorporated into more than just one class of the programm. As this is a beginners Java program/

The suit order meaning if Someone receives a 7 of hearts, and the next card is a 7 of clubs, the result should not be a tie, since Hearts has a greater suit value than clubs.

As the suits rank as : SPADES > DIAMONDS > HEARTS > CLUBS

In the Highlow class, there is a line that reads :

```
if(nextCard.getValue() == currentCard.getValue()) {
```

Which indicitates identical values, this needs to be changed however.
I have tried, compensating to learn the compareto() method, however, after hours of research I realized that it would be too complicated for me to comprehend into my code, and quite frankly even understand it. Furthermore, I have made an attempt at noting how the cases for the suits are simply used as strings, and thought that maybe they could be arranged by sum listing method, then further checked and printed. However that thought came to no avail as I felt as if I was over thinking the entire point of this exercise. The classes are below, any input would much be appreciated.

```
    public class Card {

  public final static int SPADES = 0;   // Codes for the 4 suits, plus Joker.
  public final static int HEARTS = 1;
  public final static int DIAMONDS = 2;
  public final static int CLUBS = 3;
  public final static int JOKER = 4;

  public final static int ACE = 1;      // Codes for the non-numeric cards.
  public final static int JACK = 11;    //   Cards 2 through 10 have their 
  public final static int QUEEN = 12;   //   numerical values for their codes.
  public final static int KING = 13;


  private final int suit; 

  private final int value;
  public static void main (String [] args){
  }
  public Card() {
    suit = JOKER;
    value = 1;
  }

  public Card(int theValue, int theSuit) {
    if (theSuit != SPADES && theSuit != HEARTS && theSuit != DIAMONDS && 
        theSuit != CLUBS && theSuit != JOKER)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal playing card suit");
    if (theSuit != JOKER && (theValue < 1 || theValue > 13))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal playing card value");
    value = theValue;
    suit = theSuit;
  }

  public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public String getSuitAsString() {
    switch ( suit ) {
      case SPADES:   return "Spades";
      case HEARTS:   return "Hearts";
      case DIAMONDS: return "Diamonds";
      case CLUBS:    return "Clubs";
      default:       return "Joker";
    }
  }

  public String getValueAsString() {
    if (suit == JOKER)
      return "" + value;
    else {
      switch ( value ) {
        case 1:   return "Ace";
        case 2:   return "2";
        case 3:   return "3";
        case 4:   return "4";
        case 5:   return "5";
        case 6:   return "6";
        case 7:   return "7";
        case 8:   return "8";
        case 9:   return "9";
        case 10:  return "10";
        case 11:  return "Jack";
        case 12:  return "Queen";
        default:  return "King";
      }
    }
  }   
  public String toString() {
    if (suit == JOKER) {
      if (value == 1)
        return "Joker";
      else
        return "Joker #" + value;
    }
    else {

        return getValueAsString() + " of " + getSuitAsString() ;
      }
    }

}
```

Deck CLass:

```
public class Deck {
   private Card[] deck;
   private int cardsUsed;

   public Deck() {
      this(false);  
   }

   public Deck(boolean includeJokers) {
      if (includeJokers)
         deck = new Card[54];
      else
         deck = new Card[52];
      int cardCt = 0; // How many cards have been created so far.
      for ( int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++ ) {
         for ( int value = 1; value <= 13; value++ ) {
            deck[cardCt] = new Card(value,suit);
            cardCt++;
         }
      }
      if (includeJokers) {
         deck[52] = new Card(1,Card.JOKER);
         deck[53] = new Card(2,Card.JOKER);
      }
      cardsUsed = 0;
   }

   public void shuffle() {
      for ( int i = deck.length-1; i > 0; i-- ) {
         int rand = (int)(Math.random()*(i+1));
         Card temp = deck[i];
         deck[i] = deck[rand];
         deck[rand] = temp;
      }
      cardsUsed = 0;
   }

   public int cardsLeft() {
      return deck.length - cardsUsed;
   }

   public Card dealCard() {
      if (cardsUsed == deck.length)
         throw new IllegalStateException("No cards are left in the deck.");
      cardsUsed++;
      return deck[cardsUsed - 1];
   }
   public boolean hasJokers() {
      return (deck.length == 54);
   }
}
```

Hand Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Hand {

   private ArrayList hand;   

   public Hand() {
      hand = new ArrayList();
   }

   public void clear() {
      hand.clear();
   }

   public void addCard(Card c) {
      if (c == null)
         throw new NullPointerException("Can't add a null card to a hand.");
      hand.add(c);
   }

   public void removeCard(Card c) {
      hand.remove(c);
   }

   public void removeCard(int position) {
      if (position < 0 || position >= hand.size())
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Position does not exist in hand: "
               + position);
      hand.remove(position);
   }

   public int getCardCount() {
      return hand.size();
   }

   public Card getCard(int position) {
      if (position < 0 || position >= hand.size())
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Position does not exist in hand: "
               + position);
       return (Card)hand.get(position);
   }

   public void sortBySuit() {
      ArrayList newHand = new ArrayList();
      while (hand.size() > 0) {
         int pos = 0;  // Position of minimal card.
         Card c = (Card)hand.get(0);  // Minimal card.
         for (int i = 1; i < hand.size(); i++) {
            Card c1 = (Card)hand.get(i);
            if ( c1.getSuit() < c.getSuit() ||
                    (c1.getSuit() == c.getSuit() && c1.getValue() < c.getValue()) ) {
                pos = i;
                c = c1;
            }
         }
         hand.remove(pos);
         newHand.add(c);
      }
      hand = newHand;
   }

   public void sortByValue() {
      ArrayList newHand = new ArrayList();
      while (hand.size() > 0) {
         int pos = 0;  // Position of minimal card.
         Card c = (Card)hand.get(0);  // Minimal card.
         for (int i = 1; i < hand.size(); i++) {
            Card c1 = (Card)hand.get(i);
            if ( c1.getValue() < c.getValue() ||
                    (c1.getValue() == c.getValue() && c1.getSuit() < c.getSuit()) ) {
                pos = i;
                c = c1;
            }
         }
         hand.remove(pos);
         newHand.add(c);
      }
      hand = newHand;
   }
}
```

MAIN PROGRAM CLASS

```
import java.io.*;

public class HighLow {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));  // allow input

    System.out.println("This program lets you play the simple card game,");
    System.out.println("HighLow.  A card is dealt from a deck of cards.");
    System.out.println("You have to predict whether the next card will be");
    System.out.println("higher or lower.  Your score in the game is the");
    System.out.println("number of correct predictions you make before");
    System.out.println("you guess wrong.");
    System.out.println();

    int gamesPlayed = 0;     // Number of games user has played.
    int sumOfScores = 0;     // The sum of all the scores from 
    //      all the games played.
    double averageScore;     // Average score, computed by dividing
    //      sumOfScores by gamesPlayed.
    boolean playAgain;       // Record user's response when user is 
    //   asked whether he wants to play 
    //   another game.
    do {
      int scoreThisGame;        // Score for one game.
      scoreThisGame = play();   // Play the game and get the score.
      sumOfScores += scoreThisGame;
      gamesPlayed++;
      System.out.println("Play again? ");
      playAgain = TextIO.getlnBoolean();
    } while (playAgain);

    averageScore = ((double)sumOfScores) / gamesPlayed;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You played " + gamesPlayed + " games.");
    System.out.printf("Your average score was %1.3f.\n", averageScore);

  }  // end main()

  private static int play() {

    Deck deck = new Deck();  // Get a new deck of cards, and 
    Card currentCard;  // The current card, which the user sees.
    Card nextCard;   // The next card in the deck.  The user tries
    int correctGuesses ;  // The number of correct predictions the
    char guess;   // The user's guess.  'H' if the user predicts that
    deck.shuffle();  // Shuffle the deck into a random order before
    correctGuesses = 0;
    currentCard = deck.dealCard();
    System.out.println("The first card is the " + currentCard);
    while (true) {  // Loop ends when user's prediction is wrong.

      /* Get the user's prediction, 'H' or 'L' (or 'h' or 'l'). */

      TextIO.put("Will the next card be higher (H) or lower (L)?  ");
      do {
        guess = TextIO.getlnChar();
        guess = Character.toUpperCase(guess);
        if (guess != 'H' && guess != 'L') 
          System.out.println("Please respond with H or L:  ");
      } while (guess != 'H' && guess != 'L');

      nextCard = deck.dealCard();
      System.out.println("The next card is " + nextCard);

      if(nextCard.getValue() == currentCard.getValue()) {

        System.out.println("The value is the same as the previous card.");
        System.out.println("You lose on ties.  Sorry!");
        break;  // End the game.
      }
      else if (nextCard.getValue() > currentCard.getValue()) {
        if (guess == 'H') {
          System.out.println("Your prediction was correct.");
          correctGuesses++;
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Your prediction was incorrect.");
          break;  // End the game.
        }
      }
      else {  // nextCard is lower
        if (guess == 'L') {
          System.out.println("Your prediction was correct.");
          correctGuesses++;
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Your prediction was incorrect.");
          break;  // End the game.
        }
      }
      currentCard = nextCard;
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("The card is " + currentCard);

    } // end of while loop

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The game is over.");
    System.out.println("You made " + correctGuesses 
                         + " correct predictions.");
    System.out.println();    
    return correctGuesses;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement:

```
public int getSuitValue() {
    return suit+value;
  }
```

Use getSuitValue instead of getValue in your comparison. Higher suit will always win.

You would also have to change the int value of your Suit so HEARTS > CLUBS

Comment: This could work, but it should be `return suit+value*4` so that 7 spades doesn't beat an 8 clubs.

Comment: How would it know that which suit is the higher suit?

Comment: @user2852647 Look at your code: `public final static int SPADES = 0;   // Codes for the 4 suits, plus Joker.
  public final static int HEARTS = 1;
  public final static int DIAMONDS = 2;
  public final static int CLUBS = 3;`

Comment: That does make sense, however the getsuitValue method, where would I call that in the main program since it is a new method.

Comment: @user2852647 part of the card class.

Comment: Then when you want to compare to cards you say `if(card1.getSuitValue() > card2.getSuitValue())`

Comment: What do you mean compare the cards, I thought the return statement and the changing of the private variable values was all i needed

Comment: I tried doing the return+value*4, spades happens to be beat some times by the same numerical value of another card'

Answer (score 0):

In this condition in your main method

```
if(nextCard.getValue() == currentCard.getValue()) {

    System.out.println("The value is the same as the previous card.");
    System.out.println("You lose on ties.  Sorry!");
    break;  // End the game.
}
```

Just add another if statement to then compare the suit differences and display the appropriate output

```
if(nextCard.getValue() == currentCard.getValue()) {
    if(nextCard.getSuit() > currentCard.getSuit()) {
        System.out.println("Some text");
        break;  // End the game.
    }
    else if(nextCard.getSuit() < currentCard.getSuit()){
       System.out.println("Some text");
       break;  // End the game.
    }
    else
       System.out.println("Some how you got the same card");
}
```

An even better way would be to implement a `compareTo(Card)` method inyour card class like so

```
public int compareTo(Card c)
{
    if((this.value - c.value) != 0)
        return this.value - c.value;
    else 
        return this.suit - c.suit
}
```

Then call like `nextCard.compareTo(currentCard)` if the return is 0 they are equal, if it is negative (`< 0`) then `nextCard` is lower then `currentCard`. If it is positive then (`> 0`) then `nextCard` is higher than `currentCard`

Comment: In the first way, when comparing the suits, how does the program know which suit is bigger?

Comment: Because this statement `nextCard.getSuit() > currentCard.getSuit()` checks that. It is the same as saying If the value of the suit of nextCard is greater than the value of the suit of the currentCard then this condition is true and will do the code within the next `{ }` block. It words exactly like this line of code `if (nextCard.getValue() > currentCard.getValue()) {` but it is comparing suits not values...